# Node.js - pipe() to a http response results in slow response time on ubuntu

Tags: performance, node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I noticed serious performance issue when piping a response from a service B to a client through server A. I found out this issue while investigation performance one one of our node server that mainly does proxying. We are using http-proxy for proxying, and at first I thought it was http-proxy that was slow, but I narrowed the issue to that simple snippet of code, which simply use http.get to make a request to another server and return the response to the client.

Server A (proxy):

```
/*jslint node:true nomen:true vars:true*/
var http = require('http');

function outputMs() {
    'use strict';
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getUTCMilliseconds();
    return n;
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    'use strict';
    var startTime = outputMs();

    var options = {
        hostname: '10.0.1.114',
        port: 3001,
        path: '/test'
    };

    if (req.url.indexOf('/pipe') > -1) {
        http.get(options, function (proxyRes) {
            // This is slow!!!
            proxyRes.pipe(res);
            proxyRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log('data:' + (outputMs() - startTime));
                console.log('received:' + chunk);
            });
            proxyRes.on('end', function () {
                console.log('end:' + (outputMs() - startTime));
            });
        });
    } else {
        var data;
        http.get(options, function (proxyRes) {
            // This is fast!!!
            proxyRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log('data:' + (outputMs() - startTime));
                data += chunk;
            });
            proxyRes.on('end', function () {
                console.log('end:' + (outputMs() - startTime));
                res.end(data);
            });
        });
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

Server B:

```
/*jslint node:true nomen:true vars:true*/
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    'use strict';
    res.end('Hello World');
}).listen(3001);
```

The request event seems to take the same time in both case, but the client receive the response a lot slower. Testing using curl:

Using pipe:

```
C:\github\mecs> curl -s -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null http://54.209.35.253:3000/pipe
0.265
C:\github\mecs> curl -s -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null http://54.209.35.253:3000/pipe
0.265
```

Not using pipe:

```
C:\github\mecs> curl -s -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null http://54.209.35.253:3000
0.047
C:\github\mecs> curl -s -w "%{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null http://54.209.35.253:3000
0.063
```

Both server are running on AWS on micro-instance, running Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS and node.js 0.10.21. I reproduced the issue with node 0.10.20 and 0.8.24, and on Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 and 13.10. The issue is not observed on Windows.

Does anyone experience the same problem? Any work around?

Thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: Can you narrow your test case a bit, adding some code to generate data?  There's a lot that can happen with HTTP, and it isn't clear entirely what is holding up your code.

Comment: You probably need to do something like `socket.setNoDelay([noDelay])`.  Not sure how to do that with the http module though.  My guess is one end is waiting for socket close since its a small message, and when it times out, you see the response.

Comment: @Brad Added code for server B.

Comment: @jeremy Good hint, I will look that way.

Comment: Tried setting no delay to no avail:

    proxyReq.on('socket', function (socket) {
        socket.setNoDelay(true);
    });

Comment: More info. The delay can be observed on any AWS Linux based boxed I tried (RedHat, Ubuntu, SUSE).

The delay is not observed on an Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 spawn using Vagrant (Oracle Virtual Box). This seems to point more and more to an AWS configuration issue...

Comment: @jeremy It worked! The setNoDelay() must be called on the client request, and first time I tried it was on my proxied request. Thanks a lot for the clue!
`server.on('connection', function (socket) {`
    `'use strict';`
    `console.log('server.on.connection - setNoDelay');`
    `socket.setNoDelay(true);`
`});`

Comment: @jeremy I let you submit the answer, so I can increase your reputation ;)

Comment: Thanks!  Glad it worked, I added your details to the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to do something like socket.setNoDelay([noDelay]). Not sure how to do that with the http module though. My guess is one end is waiting for socket close since its a small message, and when it times out, you see the response.

The setNoDelay() must be called on the client request, and first time I tried it was on my proxied request.

```
server.on('connection', function (socket) { 
    'use strict'; 
    console.log('server.on.connection - setNoDelay'); 
    socket.setNoDelay(true); 
});
```

Comment: It works! Turns out boxes on AWS are tuned for bandwidth vs response speed.

Comment: I really like that logging style. Is that `<OBJECT>.<FUNCTION>.<EVENT>  - <ACTION>`?

Comment: Yeah, makes it easy to track.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar error. I was able to get response much faster after I set agent in request options with **keepAlive=true of agent**.